# YII rights module roles not deleted

Tags: php, yii

my roles view code is

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'template'=>'{items}',
        'emptyText'=>Rights::t('core', 'No roles found.'),
        'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'grid-view role-table'),
        'itemsCssClass'=>'table table-striped',
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>'name',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Name'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'name-column'),
                'value'=>'$data->getGridNameLink()',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'description',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Description'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'description-column'),
            ),
            /*
            array(
                'name'=>'bizRule',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Business rule'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'bizrule-column'),
                'visible'=>Rights::module()->enableBizRule===true,
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'data',
                'header'=>Rights::t('core', 'Data'),
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'data-column'),
                'visible'=>Rights::module()->enableBizRuleData===true,
            ),
            */
            array(
                'header'=>'&nbsp;',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'htmlOptions'=>array('class'=>'actions-column'),
                'value'=>'$data->getDeleteRoleLink()',
            ),
        )
    )); ?>
```

rights/controller/authItemController

```
/**
     * Deletes an operation.
     */
    public function actionDelete()
    {
        // We only allow deletion via POST request
        if( Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest===true )
        {
            $itemName = $this->getItemName();

            // Load the item and save the name for later use
            $item = $this->_authorizer->authManager->getAuthItem($itemName);
            $item = $this->_authorizer->attachAuthItemBehavior($item);

            // Delete the item
            $this->_authorizer->authManager->removeAuthItem($itemName);

            // Delete the from Custom Table Start //

                   AnuRights::removeUserRole($itemName);
            // Delete the from Custom Table Start //

            // Set a flash message for deleting the item
            Yii::app()->user->setFlash($this->module->flashSuccessKey,
                Rights::t('core', ':name deleted.', array(':name'=>$item->getNameText()))
            );

            // If AJAX request, we should not redirect the browser
            if( isset($_POST['ajax'])===false )
                $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->getRightsReturnUrl(array('authItem/permissions')));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new CHttpException(400, Rights::t('core', 'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.'));
        }
    }
```

right/components/behaviour/Rauthitembehaviour

```
/**
    * Returns the markup for the delete role link.
    * @return string the markup.
    */
    public function getDeleteRoleLink()
    {
        // We do not want to show the delete link for the superuser role.
        if( $this->owner->name!==Rights::module()->superuserName )
        {
            return CHtml::linkButton(Rights::t('core', 'Delete'), array(
                'submit'=>array('authItem/delete', 'name'=>urlencode($this->owner->name)),
                'confirm'=>Rights::t('core', 'Are you sure you want to delete this role?'),
                'class'=>'delete-link',
                'csrf'=>Yii::app()->request->enableCsrfValidation,
            ));
        }
    }
```

im using this yii rights module https://github.com/schmunk42/yii-rights

if i click a delete button it show error

```
TypeError: jQuery.yii is undefined
...nt to delete this role?')) {jQuery.yii.submitForm(this,'/index.php/rights/authIt...
```